# Why won't my JavaCC lexer/parser accept this input?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lexer, javacc

I am creating a lexer/parser which should accept strings that belong to an infinite set of languages.
One such string is `"a <2L>AA <2U>a <2L>AA <2U>a</2U></2L></2U></2L>"`.

The set of languages is defined as follows:

**Base language, L0**

- A string from L0 consists of several blocks separated by space characters.
  At least one block must be present.
- A block is an odd-length sequence of lowercase letters (a-z).
- No spaces are allowed before the first block or after the last one.
- The number of spaces between blocks must be odd.

Example of string belonging to L0:

`zyx abcba   m xyzvv`

There is one space character between `zyx` and `abcba`, there are three spaces
between `abcba` and `m`, and only one between `m` and `xyzvv`. No other space characters are present in the string.

---

**Language L1**

- A string from L1 consists of several blocks separated by space characters.
  At least one block must be present.
- There are two kinds of blocks. A block of the first kind must be
  an even-length sequence of uppercase letters (A-Z). A block of the
  second kind must have the shape `<2U>. . .</2U>`, where `. . .` stands
  for any string from L0.
- No spaces are allowed before the first block or after the last one.
- The number of spaces between blocks must be odd.

Example of string belonging to L1:

`YZ     <2U>abc   zzz</2U> ABBA <2U>kkkkk</2U> KM`

Note that five spaces separate `YZ` and `<2U>abc zzz</2U>`, and three spaces divide `abc` from `zzz`. Otherwise single spaces are used as separators. There is no space in front of `YZ` and no space follows `KM`.

---

**Language L2**

- A string from L2 consists of several blocks separated by space characters.
  At least one block must be present.
- There are two kinds of blocks. A block of the first kind must be
  an odd-length sequence of lowercase letters (a-z). A block of the
  second kind must have the shape `<2L>. . .</2L>`, where `. . .` stands
  for any string from L1.
- No spaces are allowed before the first block or after the last one.
- The number of spaces between blocks must be odd.

Example of string belonging to L2:

`abc <2L>AA ZZ <2U>a bcd</2U></2L> z <2L><2U>abcde</2U></2L>`

Single spaces are used as separators inside the sentence given above, but any other odd number of spaces would also lead to a valid L2 sentence.

---

**Languages L{2k + 1}, k > 0**

- A string from L{2k + 1} consists of several blocks separated by space characters. At least one block must be present.
- There are two kinds of blocks. A block of the first kind must be
  an even-length sequence of uppercase letters (A-Z). A block of the
  second kind must have the shape `<2U>. . .</2U>`, where `. . .` stands
  for any string from L{2k}.
- No spaces are allowed before the first block or after the last one.
- The number of spaces between blocks must be odd.

---

**Languages L{2k + 2}, k > 0**

- A string from L{2k + 2} consists of several blocks separated by space
  characters. At least one block must be present.
- There are two kinds of blocks. A block of the first kind must be
  an odd-length sequence of lowercase letters (a-z). A block of the
  second kind must have the shape `<2L>. . .</2L>`, where `. . .` stands
  for any string from L{2k + 1}.
- No spaces are allowed before the first block or after the last one.
- The number of spaces between blocks must be odd.

---

The code for my lexer/parser is as follows:

```
PARSER_BEGIN(Assignment)

  /** A parser which determines if user's input belongs to any one of the set of acceptable languages. */
  public class Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
      try {
        Assignment parser = new Assignment(System.in);
        parser.Start();
        System.out.println("YES"); // If the user's input belongs to any of the set of acceptable languages, then print YES.
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("NO"); // If the user's input does not belong to any of the set of acceptable languages, then print NO.      
      }
    }
  }

PARSER_END(Assignment)

//** A token which matches any lowercase letter from the English alphabet. */
TOKEN :
{
  < #L_CASE_LETTER: ["a"-"z"] >
}

//* A token which matches any uppercase letter from the English alphabet. */
TOKEN:
{
  < #U_CASE_LETTER: ["A"-"Z"] >
}

//** A token which matches an odd number of lowercase letters from the English alphabet. */
TOKEN:
{
  < ODD_L_CASE_LETTER: <L_CASE_LETTER>(<L_CASE_LETTER><L_CASE_LETTER>)* >
}

//** A token which matches an even number of uppercase letters from the English alphabet. */
TOKEN:
{
  < EVEN_U_CASE_LETTERS: (<U_CASE_LETTER><U_CASE_LETTER>)+ >
}

//* A token which matches the string "<2U>" . */
TOKEN:
{
  < OPEN_UPPER: "<2U>" >
}

//* A token which matches the string "</2U>". */
TOKEN:
{
  < CLOSE_UPPER: "</2U>" >
}

//* A token which matches the string "<2L>". */
TOKEN:
{
  < OPEN_LOWER: "<2L>" >
}

//* A token which matches the string "</2L>". */
TOKEN:
{
  < CLOSE_LOWER: "</2L>" >
}

//* A token which matches an odd number of white spaces. */
TOKEN : 
{
  < ODD_WHITE_SPACE: " "(" "" ")* >
}

//* A token which matches an EOL character. */
TOKEN:
{
 < EOL: "\n" | "\r" | "\r\n" >
}

/** This production matches strings which belong to the base language L^0. */
void Start() :
{}
{
  LOOKAHEAD(3)
  <ODD_L_CASE_LETTER> (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> <ODD_L_CASE_LETTER>)* <EOL> <EOF>

  |

  NextLanguage()

  |

  LOOKAHEAD(3)
  NextLanguageTwo()

  |

  EvenLanguage()
}

/** This production matches strings which belong to language L^1. */
void NextLanguage():
{}
{
  (<OPEN_UPPER> (PseudoStart()) <CLOSE_UPPER>)+ (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> UpperOrPseudoStart())* <EOL> <EOF>

  |

  (<EVEN_U_CASE_LETTERS>)+ (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> UpperOrPseudoStart())* <EOL> <EOF>
}

/** This production matches either an even number of uppercase letters, or a string from L^0, encased within the tags <2U> and </2U>. */
void UpperOrPseudoStart() :
{}
{
  <EVEN_U_CASE_LETTERS>

  |

  <OPEN_UPPER> (PseudoStart()) <CLOSE_UPPER>
}

/** This production matches strings from L^0, in a similar way to Start(); however, the strings that it matches do not have EOL or EOF characters after them. */
void PseudoStart() :
{}
{
  <ODD_L_CASE_LETTER> (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> <ODD_L_CASE_LETTER>)*
}

/** This production matches strings which belong to language L^2. */
void NextLanguageTwo() :
{}
{
  (<ODD_L_CASE_LETTER>)+ (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> LowerOrPseudoNextLanguage())* <EOL> <EOF>

  |

  (<OPEN_LOWER> PseudoNextLanguage() <CLOSE_LOWER>)+ (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> LowerOrPseudoNextLanguage())* <EOL> <EOF>
}

/** This production matches either an odd number of lowercase letters, or a string from L^1, encased within the tags <2L> and </2L>. */
void LowerOrPseudoNextLanguage() :
{}
{
  <ODD_L_CASE_LETTER> 

  |

  <OPEN_LOWER> PseudoNextLanguage() <CLOSE_LOWER>
}

/** This production matches strings from L^1, in a similar way to NextLanguage(); however, the strings that it matches do not have EOL or EOF characters after them. */
void PseudoNextLanguage() :
{}
{
  (<OPEN_UPPER> (PseudoStart()) <CLOSE_UPPER>)+ (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> UpperOrPseudoStart())*

  |

  (<EVEN_U_CASE_LETTERS>)+ (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> UpperOrPseudoStart())*
}

/** This production matches strings which belong to any of the languages L^{2k + 2}, where k > 0 (the infinite set of even languages). */ 
void EvenLanguage() :
{}
{
  (<ODD_L_CASE_LETTER>)+ (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> EvenLanguageAuxiliary())* <EOL> <EOF>

  |

  (CommonPattern())+ (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> EvenLanguageAuxiliary())* <EOL> <EOF>
}

/** This production is an auxiliary production that helps when parsing strings from any of the even set of languages. */
void EvenLanguageAuxiliary() :
{}
{
  CommonPattern()

  |

  <ODD_L_CASE_LETTER>
}


void CommonPattern() :
{}
{
  <OPEN_LOWER> <EVEN_U_CASE_LETTERS> <ODD_WHITE_SPACE> <OPEN_UPPER> <ODD_L_CASE_LETTER> (<ODD_WHITE_SPACE> CommonPattern())+ <CLOSE_UPPER> <CLOSE_LOWER>
}
```

Several times now, I have inputted the string `"a <2L>AA <2U>a <2L>AA <2U>a</2U></2L></2U></2L>"`.
However, each time, `NO` is printed out on the terminal.
I have looked through my code carefully several times, checking the order in which I think the input string should be parsed; but, I haven't been able to find any errors in my logic or reasons why the string isn't being accepted.

Could I have some suggestions as to why it isn't being accepted, please?

Comment: If you're not prepared to describe the language at least as far as giving a grammar for it, it's difficult to see how anyone can help you.

Comment: @EJP: sorry for this.  I didn't realise that it would cause such difficulty. I will edit my questions right away.

Comment: Have you tried any of JavaCC's debug options?  I would suggest that you do that to see where your expectation and reality diverge.

Comment: What is the motivation for parsing this language? Is it just a meaningless homework assignment or is there an application in mind?

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell It's a meaningful homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps helped to solve the problem.

1. Run the following code:
   `javacc -debug_parser Assignment.jj`
   `javac Assignment*.java`
2. Then, run the lexer/parser (by typing `java Assignment`) and then input the string:
   `"a <2L>AA <2U>a <2L>AA <2U>a</2U></2L></2U></2L>"`
3. The resulting trace of parser actions shows that the production `NextLangaugeTwo()` is called on this string, rather than the desired `EvenLanguage()` production.
4. Tracing through `NextLangaugeTwo()` shows that it matches the first eight tokens in the input string.
5. So, using a lookahead of 9, although inefficient, causes the input string to be accepted.  That is, modify the `Start()` production by changing the second lookahead value (just above the call to `NextLanguageTwo()`) from 3 to 9.

Comment: I really don't like the suggestion to change the lookahead from 3 to 9 unless there is an analysis to show that there is no string that will require 10.  On the other hand, the advice to use "debug_parser" is spot on; I wish everyone with this sort of question would do at least this basic level of investigation before posting.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell I haven't been able to find another way around the issue just yet.  Also, this was the first time that I learnt that debug_parser is able to do this.  Sorry if the post was an inconvenience.

Comment: Both `NextLanguageTwo` and `EvenLanguage` can start with any positive number of `<ODD_L_CASE_LETTER>` tokens, so it is clear that any finite bound on the lookahead is going to be insufficient. You might try a syntactic lookahead.

Comment: Or you might try factoring out the common prefix.  That's probably what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your inputs being accepted? I have copied your code over to my computer and have found that any correct input (as far as I can tell from the definition of your language), it always outputs 'NO'.

Comment: yes.  For instance, the string `"YZ     <2U>abc   zzz</2U> ABBA <2U>kkkkk</2U> KM"` is accepted.  That is a string which is in L1 and it is accepted on my terminal.

Comment: Very strange, even this string outputs 'NO' on my terminal using your exact program.

Comment: I'm going to try again.  I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: It's still working, and this time I copied the exact lexer/parser code used in this post.  I'm going to work on @TheodoreNorvell's comment above.